# 'Time' being changed to a 'Datetime' after being added to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, casting, model, controller

My controller creates something called `start_time`. When I print `start_time`'s value before it's added to a `LittleClassSession` hash, here's what I get:

```
22:45:00
```

Okay, it looks like a value with the type `time`. After it's added to the hash, I ask the controller what the `:start_time` value is.

```
@little_class_session = LittleClassSession.new({
  ...
  :start_time => start_time
})

puts @little_class_session.start_time
```

Here's what it puts:

```
2000-01-01 22:45:00 UTC
```

It appears to be formatted like a `datetime`, but asking what the `.class` of the `start_time` attribute is returns:

```
Time
```

The `LittleClassSession` `start_time` column is a `time` in the table (I can verify this by checking the type in the Rails console) but was a `datetime` when the model was created.

What could be causing this?

Comment: The datatype of `start_time` is `datetime` in your database schema?

Comment: It's `time`. It was `datetime` when the model was created, but I successfully performed a migration to convert it to a `time` (I can verify this by checking the column's type in the console).

Comment: What's the output of `start_time.class`?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using a sqlite db.

Comment: I think the issue here may be that sqlite has neither TIME or DATETIME types: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your database may support a "time" column (meaning just a time with no date information), Rails by default does not (largely because neither does Ruby's standard library -- even a `Time` contains date information). As such, when you assign it to your model, Rails is coercing it into the type it knows how to deal with, `DateTime`. So, you have a few options:

1. Ignore the date part of the time when you use it.
2. Use a gem like [tod](https://github.com/JackC/tod) to deal with your time-only types, and follow the guidelines in the README for hooking it up to Rails.
3. Store `start_time_hour` and `start_time_minutes` in two separate columns, and work with them as needed (e.g, `Date.current + start_time_hour.hours + start_time_minutes.minutes`).

Hope that helps!